# Memory Change on OSX

Tags: macos, memory, mach

I made an example that writes into process memory using task_for_pid() and mach_vm_write().

```
task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &target_task);
mach_vm_write(target_task, address, '?', local_size);
```

If some of process writes data to the specified address in the task of my application, how can I monitor the change of memory?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Using mach_vm_write (like using WriteProcessMemory in Windows or ptrace(2) in Linux) provides no notification for the written process. Your only choices are:

A) use an IPC object between the writing and victim task
B) spawn a thread in the victim task to monitor changes on that region of memory. This has the obvious disadvantage of continuous polling. Though a more advanced solution would be to create a remote thread in the task you are writing to (which you can, since you got the task port by now), and have it do something.